# How to detect screen size change object style using jQuery？

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a beginner student of jQuery!
First of all, I am very sorry that my English is not good, but I will try to describe my problem completely. Thank you.

Now I want to practice using jQuery to change the color of the box when the browser is below 768px. I checked this writing method on the Internet, but I still can't achieve the effect. Would you please help me to check if there is any problem with the grammar?

Thank you for watching.`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    let width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768) {
      $('.box').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #8ec06c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: 1) Your code is already working, you're just setting the wrong property. Change `color` to `background-color` 2) Do not use JS for updating the UI based on available screen size. This is what [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are for. They are purpose designed for it and perform *much* better than JS does.

Comment: Thank you for your response
However, I changed the background-color and still cannot achieve the effect of changing color at 768px. Is there any error on any side?

Thank you for telling me that I should use more @media, but I am currently practicing using jQuery so there is no way to use CSS. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: In which case check the console in devtools for an error elsewhere in the code as the example shown works fine (once you correct the property): https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0jqaxohr/

Comment: Thank you very much, I did try!
It turned out that I forgot to introduce the CDN of jQuery in my IDE. As expected, I was a beginner and made a stupid mistake that should not be made. Thank you for your instruction.